QField Syncing Issues - Layers could not be loaded in QField
I set up a QField project in QGIS by first creating a project and then packaging it for QField. When I sync for the first time it works perfectly and the layers show up in the app as I expect. We have some of the collaborators in the field adding points to layers.
That worked fine last week, but suddenly now all the layers don't show up in the app. the error message is:

"The following layers could not be loaded, please review those and
reconfigure the QGIS project".

I am not sure what to do since the field data they acquired is very valuable, and I don't want to lose the data. The files still show up on QField Cloud on the web.
Can someone recommend safe approach to take to make sure that no data is lost?
Machine: Apple M3 Max - MacOS Sonoma Version 14.5 (23F79)
QGIS: 3.34 LTR
QField: 3.3.7

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] this to focus on your most pressing issue, providing complete details on what you have attempted. I'd recommnd waiting to ask the next Question until after you've got a handle on what is needed to make an answerable Question.

Please ask one question at the time. Thanks.
